# Remove escape and line breaks from pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with a bunch of messy text data. It looks something like this:

```
name                    email
John Doe                jdoe@gmail.com
Anthony Fiorella\nPhD   afiorella@gmail.com
Xu "Chris" Chang        xcchang@hotmail.com
```

I've tried a few things to remove the escape characters, like this

```
df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: `df.replace(r'\n', ' ', regex=True)` you do not need to use raw strings with `\\n` it is either `r'\n'` or `'\\n'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
df["name"].replace(to_replace=r"\n", value=" ", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

There is additional information available in the official documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)